# I wanna make table has only most newest data each user_id in models.py

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna make Transaction table in models.py.
I wanna parse excel& make dictionary and put the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary. There is 2 excels
[image: excel1]
[image: excel2]

I read 1st Excel,and the data is in User.
Now I wanna read 2nd Excel,but if i do so,user_id=1 Blear&user_id=2 Tom 's data has 2 data are from Excel1&2.So,I wanna try to make a table has only most newest data each user_id.
models.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dormitory = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How can I make it?How can I sort most newest data and put them in model?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need use [get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

while you read the excel you can try this logic:

```
user_id = 'GET VALUE FROM EXCEL'
user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
user.nationality = 'GET VALUE FROM EXCEL'
# some other data
user.save()
```

Comment: Thx ur comments.Do you think I should write ur codes in views.py not models.py?And what shoud I write in 'GET VALUE FROM EXCEL'?